# Convert part of DOS/Windows batch to linux shell

Tags: windows, linux, shell, batch-file

I'd be glad if someone could tell me what the following lines should look like under linux bin/bash script:

```
rand1=%RANDOM%
rand2=%rand1:~1,2%
if %rand2% LSS 10 rand2=%rand2%+10
set /a macc6=%rand2%
```

Don't even know if there is even an equivalent to %RANDOM% to start with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash has `$RANDOM` ([Bash variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables))

The step-by-step translation:

```
rand1=$RANDOM
rand2=$((rand1 % 100))
(( rand2 < 10 )) && (( rand2 += 10 ))
export macc6=$rand2
```

Without the temp variables:

```
export macc6=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
(( macc6 < 10 )) && (( macc6 += 10 ))
```